# Persistent read/write/cksum errors on raidz2 even after replacing disks (Netapp DS4243)

Tags: zfs

I have a once-working, now degraded zfs pool configured as follows, which I have been attempting to repair for weeks now by replacing and re-replacing disks only to have the same problems on the same bays reappear.

Couple of weeks ago

```
        NAME                        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        zpool                       DEGRADED     0     0     0
          raidz2-0                  DEGRADED     0     0     0
            wwn-0x50000c900040b558  ONLINE       3   159     0
            wwn-0x50000c900040a134  ONLINE       0     0     0
            wwn-0x50000c900040f8b0  ONLINE       0     0     0
            wwn-0x50000c90003fd4c4  ONLINE       0     0     0
            wwn-0x50000c90003fe7fc  ONLINE       0     0     0
            wwn-0x50000c9000409f8c  ONLINE       0     0     0
            scsi-3500605ba010cb160  ONLINE       0     0     0
            wwn-0x50000c900015436c  ONLINE       0     0     0
            replacing-8             UNAVAIL      3 35.9K     0  insufficient replicas
              2597997485925153301   FAULTED      0     0     0  was /dev/sdl1
              sdaa                  FAULTED     20 27.0K     0  corrupted data
              sdaa                  FAULTED      3 9.27K     0  too many errors
            wwn-0x50000c900040a0a0  ONLINE   5.74K 78.3K     0
            wwn-0x50000c90004104fc  ONLINE       0     0     0
            wwn-0x50000c90003fc900  ONLINE       0     0     0
          raidz2-1                  ONLINE       0     0     0
            wwn-0x500605ba00776c40  ONLINE       3     2     2
            wwn-0x500605ba00a89b18  ONLINE       0     0     0
            wwn-0x50000c90003fc944  ONLINE       0     0     0
            wwn-0x50000c90003fbdf0  ONLINE       0     0     0
            wwn-0x50000c90003fbdf4  ONLINE       0     0     0
            wwn-0x50000c9000409f24  ONLINE       0     0     0
            wwn-0x500605ba0108354c  ONLINE       0     0     0
            wwn-0x500605ba00bfceec  ONLINE       0     0     0
            wwn-0x50000c900040ac94  ONLINE       0     0     0
            wwn-0x50000c900040f968  ONLINE       0     0     0
            wwn-0x50000c90003fbe10  ONLINE       0     0     0
            wwn-0x50000c900040a828  ONLINE       0     0     0
        special
          mirror-2                  ONLINE       0     0     0
            wwn-0x5001b444a7ae7a55  ONLINE       0     0     0
            wwn-0x5001b444a7ae7a57  ONLINE       0     0     0
```

After some more disk replacements, resilverings and resets:

```
        NAME                                     STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        zpool                                    DEGRADED     0     0     0
          raidz2-0                               DEGRADED     0     0     0
            wwn-0x50000c900040b558               ONLINE       0     0     0
            wwn-0x50000c900040a134               ONLINE       0     0     0
            wwn-0x50000c900040f8b0               ONLINE       0     0     0
            wwn-0x50000c90003fd4c4               ONLINE       0     0     0
            wwn-0x50000c90003fe7fc               ONLINE       0     0     0
            wwn-0x50000c9000409f8c               ONLINE       0     0     0
            scsi-3500605ba010cb160               ONLINE       0     0     0
            wwn-0x50000c900015436c               ONLINE       0     0     0
            usb-LITEON_UITRA1_00000000006BF-0:0  DEGRADED     0     0 18.0K  too many errors  (resilvering)
            replacing-9                          DEGRADED    52  318K 2.01K
              old                                OFFLINE      0     0     0  block size: 512B configured, 4096B native
              wwn-0x50000c900040a0a0             ONLINE      17 1.58M     0  block size: 512B configured, 4096B native  (resilvering)
            wwn-0x50000c90004104fc               ONLINE       0     0     0
            wwn-0x50000c90003fc900               ONLINE       0     0     0
          raidz2-1                               ONLINE       0     0     0
            wwn-0x500605ba00776c40               ONLINE       0     0     0
            wwn-0x500605ba00a89b18               ONLINE       0     0     0
            wwn-0x50000c90003fc944               ONLINE       0     0     0
            wwn-0x50000c90003fbdf0               ONLINE       0     0     0
            wwn-0x50000c90003fbdf4               ONLINE       0     0     0
            wwn-0x50000c9000409f24               ONLINE       0     0     0
            wwn-0x500605ba0108354c               ONLINE       0     0     0
            wwn-0x500605ba00bfceec               ONLINE       0     0     0
            wwn-0x50000c900040ac94               ONLINE       0     0     0
            wwn-0x50000c900040f968               ONLINE       0     0     0
            wwn-0x50000c90003fbe10               ONLINE       0     0     0
            wwn-0x50000c900040a828               ONLINE       0     0     0
        special
          mirror-2                               ONLINE       0     0     0
            wwn-0x5001b444a7ae7a55               ONLINE       0     0     0
            wwn-0x5001b444a7ae7a57               ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors
```

It's a 24-spindle Netapp DS4243 and the errors have mostly related to one of three problematic drive bays.

| Problem Bay | Problem | Tests |
| --- | --- | --- |
| usb-LITEON_UITRA1_00000000006BF-0:0 | no disk will stay online in this bay for more than a few minutes, so it was replaced with a USB enclosure | Tested & resilvered with four disks including a brand new one. Problem persisted, so it was replaced with a USB enclosure, which works, but is reporting a high error count, maybe due to the disk in the USB enclosure but it is weird as the disk was tested with HD sentinel. |
| wwn-0x50000c900040a0a0 | usually fine but has gone offline a few times, has erratic read-write errors towards the end of resilvering operation | Tested & resilvered with three disks including a brand new one. Problem persists |
| wwn-0x50000c900040b558 | has gone offline only once, has erratic read-write errors but fewer than wwn-0x50000c900040a0a0 | Tested & resilvered with two different disks. Problem persists |

[image: The problem bays are not physically adjacent and appear randomly positioned] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/GkrGG.jpg). The bays are internally connected in the Netapp device. I just insert the drives into the hotswap bays and have a SAS HD cable running straight to the SAS HBA adapter. The only other physical manipulation, is I believe the Netapp has had an IOM6 controller fitted in the past.

The smartctl stats for wwn-0x50000c900040a0a0 and wwn-0x50000c900040b558 both show no disk errors but, a value of 28 for "Non-medium error count" on wwn-0x50000c900040a0a0, which I gather implies possibility of an interface error, and damned if I know why.

Unfortunately it's a pool I can't afford to lose and I don't want to be forever resilvering (I'm currently resilvering only with brand new disks but still getting the errors).

**Update - Fix Found???**
Replacing the old Emulex SATA->SAS interposer boards with LSI equivalents, quite unexpectedly, has been resolving the issue on the affected bays.

I've still got a new HD SAS cable coming with a thicker wire gauge, since it could all be related, but so far so good.

Comment: this looks like a hardware fault with either a) some of the NAS unit's drive bays (most likely) or b) the SAS cable.  There's also an outside chance that the HBA adaptor is faulty, but that's unlikely.    So, try replacing the cable first (because that's the cheapest possible fix). Then try a different adaptor, or maybe a different port on the adaptor (one of my LSI 8-port cards has a dodgy socket).  If that doesn't help, get an electronics tech to carefully examine the soldering on the problematic bays.  or return the unit for a warranty replacement.

Comment: Finally, there have been various issues over the years when combining SAS expanders with SATA drives. I don't know what the current state is WRT expanders, but that might be worth looking into if your NAS unit uses SAS expanders.    See [Using SATA drives with SAS shared backplane?](https://serverfault.com/questions/451555/using-sata-drives-with-sas-shared-backplane) - there's a good answer with a link to an openzfs bug report about this.    https://www.servethehome.com/ should also have articles on this topic.

Comment: Thanks @cas for pointing me in the right direction. https://www.reddit.com/r/homelab/comments/9nczxw/ds4243_disks_resetting_going_offline_and_udma_crc/ has the same DS4243, IOM6 and cable type cominbation and the same problem, so I will indeed have to go the route of changing IOM6 or the cable (kind of have to change IOM6 to change the cable)

Comment: *Unfortunately it's a pool I can't afford to lose*  You do have good backups then...

Comment: Just an update for anyone who cares - after discovering the LSI interposer worked but the Emulex wasn't, I thought I'd try replacing the external mini SAS cable. So far, so good - the Emulex interposers now are working as well. The new cable is slightly thicker 28awg instead of 30awg and slightly shorter 2m instead of 3m. So it may ultimately have been a cable issue. So the lesson might be, be careful of the lesser unbranded cables (the working cable is also unbranded but a higher standard)